# Is dispatching Redux actions considered expensive?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been using the React - Redux - Typescript stack for a while and I'm loving it so far. However, since I'm quite new to Redux, I've been wondering about this certain topic. **Is dispatching Redux actions (and thunks) considered expensive operations and should be used sparingly, or should it be used as much as setState is used?**

Let's say the Redux state has a single reducer that manages user information:

```
const initialState = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: ''
}
```

And to change these fields, let say we have actions like `setFirstName`, `setLastName`, etc... just for simplicity's sake.

And let's say in the View I have an input element in `render()`:

```
<input onChange={this.firstNameInputChangeListener} placeholder="First Name"/>
```

Considering `setFirstName` has been mapped to the component:

```
export default connect(state => state, { setFirstName })(ThisComponent);
```

Is it optimal to dispatch an action every time there's a change in the input:

```
public firstNameInputChangeListener = (event) => {
  this.props.setFirstName(event.target.value);
}
```

Or is it better to create local component state, bind the state to the Change Listener and only dispatch an action when the form is submitted:

```
public state = {
  firstName: this.props.firstName;
}

public firstNameInputChangeListener = (event) => {
  this.setState({ firstName: event.target.value });
}

public submitButtonListener = (event) => {
  this.props.setFirstName(this.state.firstName);
}
```

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of actually dispatching an action is:

- Passing the action through each middleware
- Executing the root reducer function, which is probably split up into several slice reducers if you're using `combineReducers()`
- Calling all of the store subscription callbacks

Generally, the middleware and the reducer logic are not the bottlenecks - it's updating the UI that can be expensive.  With React-Redux, each connected component instance is a separate subscriber.  If you have a connected List with 10000 connected ListItems, that's 10001 subscribers.

The Redux FAQ has entries discussing [app performance and scalability](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#how-well-does-redux-scale-in-terms-of-performance-and-architecture), and [ways to cut down on subscriber notifications](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-store-update-events).

For a form specifically, it's unlikely that the rest of the app *needs* to be updated on every keystroke in the form.  For that, it's very reasonable to debounce the dispatch.  My blog post [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling and Data Editing](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/) shows a reusable component that can wrap inputs or forms to enable fast updates in the UI, while also debouncing the dispatch of a Redux action.

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much solves my question!

So to wrap up your answer, it would be fine if we abuse pure actions with no side effects or subscribers and sparingly use actions that have asynchronous middlewares or a lot of subscribers and callbacks. Is this correct?

Comment: No. All subscriber callbacks are run _every_ time an action reaches the main store and the reducer runs, even if no state is updated as a result. Subscribers do not subscribe to specific actions - they are notified simply because _any_ action was dispatched.  Now, `connect` attempts to optimize behavior by checking to see if the root state value has changed at all, and bailing out immediately if it's the same, but that's still a function call and a comparison.  On the flip side, if a middleware intercepts an action and doesn't pass it on to the store, subscribers aren't notified at all.

Comment: I see. So to paraphrase, I can abuse middlewares that don't necessarily dispatch an action every time. Thanks to _connect_, I can also abuse actions that don't necessarily change the state every time.

In my original question, it's best to lazily capture the input in the component state and dispatch an action only when the form is submitted. Is that correct?

Comment: Roughly, yes. As always, actual perf behavior will depend on how your own app is set up. But, yes, one way to minimize dispatched actions is to debounce dispatching from form inputs, or only dispatch when the user is completing the form.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! This is incredibly useful.